# TableView not displaying Cell Content

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview, core-data

I am Using `core data` as my data base. Inside my `UITableView` I have a button to add projects , But at this moment I only Use it to add names. But the names I add do not display on the tableview.
I think my problem is that I need to repopulate my projectArray, how and where do I do that.
Here is my code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return [_projectArray count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    Project* project = _projectArray[indexPath.row];
    static NSString *cellID = @"TableCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = project.name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"prooo";
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    return cell;

}
```

Here is my button code:

```
- (IBAction)addProjectButton:(id)sender {
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter new project name."
                                                message:nil
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];

alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;

[alert show];

UITextField *textField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
textField.placeholder = @"Project Name";


}
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
if (buttonIndex != alertView.cancelButtonIndex) {
    UITextField *field = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
    AppDelegate *delegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    NSManagedObject *object =[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Project" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [object setValue:field.text forKey:@"name"];

    NSError *error;
    [context save:&error];
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Whoops %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];

} else {

    NSLog(@"cancel");
}
}
```

And here is my ViewWillAppear Code , where I fetch info:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:nil];

AppDelegate *delegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [delegate managedObjectContext];

//load project
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Project" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetch setEntity:entity];
NSError *error;
_projectArray = [context executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];
}
```

Comment: where do you set tableView's datasource and delegate?

Comment: also you should evaluate the error object from the fetch request.

Answer (score 1):

There are many things you can do. To make it a good code, I will suggest write a method that reloads your array. Like this

```
-(void) reloadArray
{
    AppDelegate *delegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [delegate managedObjectContext];

    //load project
    NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Project" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetch setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error;
    _projectArray = [context executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];
}
```

Then replace your viewDidAppear like this -

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [super viewWillAppear:nil];

    [self reloadArray];
}
```

Also in your numberOfSectionsInTableView: method, make this change -

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{
    [self reloadArray];
    return 1;
}
```

And it should do the magic...

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the dataSource and delegate properties of tableView?

```
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
```

Comment: Yes I have but it has no effect on the outcome

Answer (score 0):

Change This :

```
 NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Project" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetch setEntity:entity];
NSError *error;
_projectArray = [context executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];
```

To:

```
 _projectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
 NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Project" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetch setEntity:entity];
NSManagedObject *object = nil;
NSError *error;
NSArray *result = [context executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];

 for (int i = 0; i <  [result count]; i ++) {
 object = [result objectAtIndex:i];
 [_projectArray setObject:[object valueForKey:@"name"]
}
```

Comment: There is no interface for the array where it declares setObject

Comment: Declare your array as NSMtableArray and initialise it

Comment: OK I have changed it to a mutable array, can you just help me from there?

Comment: change `cell.textLabel.text = [_projectArray objectAtindex: indexPath.row];`

Comment: First make sure you are fetching the data properly. And populating the array .

Comment: In my output it shows that the data is being fetched and it shows that the count of the rows in the table view are increasing

Comment: Sorry instead of setObject try addObject

Comment: I have now found out that my TableView Code is not being red at all, But the delegate datasource and everything is set, What can be the probleme

Comment: @LenvanZyl if your array is empty it won't go to `tableview datasource` code. So first you have to make sure that your array is getting properly populated.

Comment: try to have some hardcoded data in your project array and see.. if your data gets load that means you are not fetching the data properly from core data

Comment: Thank you, looks like that was the problem, Had to pre populate the array with a default project